# Django ORM Query to find average distance between dates

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have three models:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField()

class Comments(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    action = models.ForeignKey(Label, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'group__name': 'action'}, related_name='action_label')
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group = models.ForeignKey(LabelGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My goal is to get an **average timespan** between Ticket.date (opened) and the latest Comment.date of type Label.name = containment.  Lastly, I want to pass in a date range `(start_date, end_date)` to limit to only tickets within that time period.

Ultimately, I want to return:

```
{
avg_time_to_contain: 37,
avg_time_to_recover: 157
}
```

from a DRF view.

The query set I have so far is:

```
queryset = Comments.objects.filter(ticket__date__gte=start_date, ticket__date__lte=end_date).filter(action__name__icontains="containment").distinct(ticket).aggregate(avg_containment=Avg(F(date)- F(ticket__date)))
```

I am getting an error, saying incident is not defined.  I believe that is due to my distinct function but I am having a hard time getting my brain to translate into what I am after.

Pseudo code for the query (in my thinking),

- Grab comments that have tickets (FK) with dates between start / end date
- Filter by the action (FK) name having the work containment
- Just grab one distinct ticket at a time (feel like I am not doing this right, basically I want to just have the last entry for each ticket to be able to pull the diff between open & last containment comment, and then average the difference in time)
- Get the average of the containment date comment - the open date.

ERROR MSG:

> NameError at /api/timetocontain/
>
> name 'ticket' is not defined
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1/api/timetocontain/
> Django Version:   4.1.3 Exception Type:   NameError Exception Value:
>
> name 'ticket' is not defined

Comment: Could you post the actual error you're getting?

Comment: Edited, Error added

Comment: To fix that error you need to pass in `ticket` as a string, i.e. `.distinct('ticket')`

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: Instead of "distincting" tickets i think you should stick to this phrase `and the latest Comment.date` and build the query which finds the only comment for each ticket. By finding distinct ticket ids you may fix performance issues perhaps - by reusing them in the final query. But aggregation within this approach would give avg of all date distances if there are multiple comments with given action per ticket. If you find the only comment per ticket there will be no need in distinct then. currently distinct is an attempt to hide major flaw of the query.

Comment: Thanks everyone, that is very helpful.  Appreciate both the syntactical help as well as the logic.  Felt like my logic was flawed but couldn't exactly come up with why.  Thank you.